# Make th value NULL or if empty dont do the where

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have now :

```
$inhoud = $_POST['inhoud'];
if($inhoud == "") {
    echo $inhoud;
    $inhoud = NULL;
    echo $inhoud;
}

$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT bestanden.id AS id,
               bestanden.uploader AS uploader,
               bestanden.name AS name,
               bestanden.mime AS mime,
               bestanden.size AS size,
               bestanden.created AS created,
               zoeken.open_id AS open_id,
               zoeken.woord AS woord
        FROM bestanden
        LEFT JOIN zoeken ON bestanden.id = zoeken.open_id 
        WHERE zoeken.woord = "' . $inhoud . '" AND
              bestanden.name LIKE "%' . $_POST['naam'] . '%" AND
              bestanden.mime LIKE "%' . $_POST['formaat'] . '%"
              AND bestanden.created LIKE "%' . $_POST['datum'] . '%";';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

But when I search and $inhoud is empty, I got no results because they dont have an empty( " " ) (inhoud)space there. Is it possible to use an if or something in my mysql_query?

Comment: Try to use mysqli instead of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

You can try with:

```
$inhoud = $_POST['inhoud'];
if ($inhoud == "") {
    echo $inhoud;
    $inhoud = NULL;
    echo $inhoud;
}

$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT bestanden.id AS id,
               bestanden.uploader AS uploader,
               bestanden.name AS name,
               bestanden.mime AS mime,
               bestanden.size AS size,
               bestanden.created AS created,
               zoeken.open_id AS open_id,
               zoeken.woord AS woord
        FROM bestanden
        LEFT JOIN zoeken ON bestanden.id = zoeken.open_id 
        WHERE ';
if(!empty($inhoud)) {
    $sql .= 'zoeken.woord = "' . $inhoud . '" AND';
}
$sql .= 'bestanden.name LIKE "%' . $_POST['naam'] . '%" AND
         bestanden.mime LIKE "%' . $_POST['formaat'] . '%"
         AND bestanden.created LIKE "%' . $_POST['datum'] . '%";';

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT bestanden.id AS id, bestanden.uploader AS uploader, bestanden.name AS name, bestanden.mime AS mime, bestanden.size AS size, bestanden.created AS created, zoeken.open_id AS open_id, zoeken.woord AS woord FROM bestanden LEFT JOIN zoeken ON bestanden.id = zoeken.open_id 
    WHERE 1=1';
if(!empty($inhoud))
    $sql.=' AND zoeken.woord="' . $inhoud . '"';
$sql.=' AND bestanden.name LIKE "%' . $_POST['naam'] . '%" AND bestanden.mime LIKE "%' . $_POST['formaat'] . '%" AND bestanden.created LIKE "%' . $_POST['datum'] . '%"';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use empty function

```
empty($inhound);
```

Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe strlen() ?

```
if(strlen($inhoud)>0){
    $sql.=' AND zoeken.woord="' . $inhoud . '"';
    $sql.=' AND bestanden.name LIKE "%' . $_POST['naam'] . '%" AND
    bestanden.mime LIKE "%' .         $_POST['formaat'] . '%" AND 
    bestanden.created LIKE "%' . $_POST['datum'] . '%"';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
 }else{
    //error fill in search term
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't assume that `$_POST[...]` is set under any circumstances (unless you've already checked that it **is** set). Correct usage would be:

```
$inhoud = null:
if( isset( $_POST['inhound'])){
    $inhound = trim( $_POST['inhound']); // Trim to prevent strings like "    "
    if( strlen( $inhound) < 1){
        $inhound = null;
    }
}
```

Also note that [`mysql_*` family is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) so rather use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), having PDO example (using [`PDO::Prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php),  [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [`PDOStatement::Execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)):

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT bestanden.id AS id, bestanden.uploader AS uploader,
            bestanden.name AS name, bestanden.mime AS mime,
            bestanden.size AS size, bestanden.created AS created,
            zoeken.open_id AS open_id, zoeken.woord AS woord
       FROM bestanden
       LEFT JOIN zoeken ON bestanden.id = zoeken.open_id 
       WHERE zoeken.woord=:inhound
           AND bestanden.name LIKE :naam
           AND bestanden.mime LIKE :formaat
           AND bestanden.created LIKE :date';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

$sth->bindParam(':naam', isset( $_POST['naam']) ? '%' . $_POST['naam'] . '%', '%');
$sth->bindParam(':formaat', isset( $_POST['formaat']) ? '%'.$_POST['formaat'].'%', '%');
$sth->bindParam(':naam', isset( $_POST['date']) ? '%' . $_POST['date'] . '%', '%');
$sth->bindParam(':inhound', is_null( $inhound) ? '%' . $inhound . '%', '%');

$sth->execute();
$sth->fetchAll();
```